# Why does the [pattern] not working in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my `.ts` component file, I've a variable like (to restrict an invalid phone number being entered),

```
public phonePattern = ^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,3})+$;
```

And in my component html file, I've a text box declared as,

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.phone" [pattern]="phonePattern" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" />
```

Here the `[pattern]` binding doesn't seem to be working.. Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you use a custom validator with that Regex?

Comment: @Niladri, Yes I can!. But just curious to know why this particular way doesn't give me the result. :-)

Comment: see [this](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-pattern-validation-example)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you consider a valid phone number?

Comment: Exactly my problem, why does Angular not take into account a regex with validation. I mean, it is not that I put a regex for fun in there? Why do I have to do it in the component? And why is `[pattern]` not binding indeed? Is this a bug in newer versions or is it by design?

Answer (score 2):

Try initializing the regex like this:

```
phonePattern = /^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,3})+$/;
```

And do verify whether your regex pattern is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks.. Same result :(

Answer (score 1):

Use Model driven forms it has inbuilt methods to validate regular expressions.

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
.
.
.
class ModelFormComponent implements OnInit {
  myform: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    myform = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormGroup({
            firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required), 
            lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        }),
        email: new FormControl('', [ 
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern("[^ @]*@[^ @]*") 
        ]),
        password: new FormControl('', [
            Validators.minLength(8), 
            Validators.required
        ]),
        language: new FormControl() 
    });
  }
}
```

here is sample of model driven form [model driven forms](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/forms/model-driven-validation/)

Comment: Thanks guru!.. I'm not dealing with reactive forms, Hence this solution won't workout in my case.

Comment: If you don't have very complicated forms or just one input this is overkill imo. What happened to regex validation in HTML with Angular. I remember it working in older versions of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Well what I ended up doing is something like this, in the component:

```
number;
matchesRegex; //Define method

  ngOnInit() {
    //set method
    this.matchesRegex = function () {
      if (this.number === null) {
        return false;
      }
      return this.number.match(/^-?[1-9]?\d[,]-?[1-9]?\d$/gm);
    }
  }
```

Then in my HTML template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="number" [ngClass] = "{'is-valid': matchesRegex()}">
```

This works wonderfully since it is checked every cycle and your value is updated when the user types. You can use this to block submission or disable a button or whatever. I just used it for a class. The native validator stops you from submitting an invalid pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Create a phone validation directive.

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[phone]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: PhoneDirective, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class PhoneDirective implements Validator {
  constructor() {}

  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
    if (c.value && !/^-?[1-9]?\d[,]-?[1-9]?\d$/gm.test(c.value)) {
      return {
        phone: 'Invalid phone number'
      };
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Now you can just add the phone attribute to your input

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.phone" phone placeholder="Enter Phone Number" />
```